# HTML code navigation menu in the header look and feel section of confluence not overlaying properly

Tags: html, css, confluence

I am trying to edit our space in confluence and add a navigation menu globally in our space. I am doing this at the very top of the page instead of doing a page tree becase we can't touch the side bar (government standards). Anyway, I did a horizontal navigation menu at the top of the header page. I put it in Space tools -> look and feel -> sidebar, header, footer. I pasted my HTML and CSS code in the header part.

This works fine except for one problem: When I highlight the menu in order to bring up the sub menu, it is not overlaying properly. Part of the page covers the sub menu. I attached a couple of screenshots on what I mean.

Any workaround in order to make this work? I tested this on just pure HTML without confluence and there is no problem there. I am still designing the navigation bar so don't judge ;)

Edit: Also, on the first pciture, when I try to hover past "Hardware Support" which is the one with the arrow pointing, the sub menu disappers. It would not go past it.

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

Here is the HTML:

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
  margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul.color
{
  background-color: #3572B0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
  display:block;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:32px;
  padding:0 15px;
  font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}


#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
  background:#2A67A5
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
  float:none;
  width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
  line-height:120%;
  padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
  top:0;
  left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
  display:block;
  background:#3572B0;
}
```

```html
    <h1>Contracts Department</h1>
    <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul class="color">
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Contracts">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Latest+Announcements">Latest Announcements</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/SSC+PAC+Centerwide+Contracting+Strategy">SSC PAC Centerwide Contracting Strategy</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Items+of+Interest">Items of Interest</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Contracts+Department">Contracts Department</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12136303">Policy & Procedures</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/SPAWAR+Instructions">SPAWAR Instructions</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Checklists+Repository">Checklists Repository</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135507">Local IPMs, IBBs, PCIBs, & CIBs</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Policy+Communication+Methods">Policy Communication Methods</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135265">Acquisition Regulations & Guidance</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135203">Forms & Tools</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Internal+Self+Assessments">Internal Self Assessments</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12136180">Workforce Management & Development</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Competency+Training">Competency Training</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Information+Forum">Information Forum</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12136213">PR/Market Research/JNCP Training</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Presentations+and+Supplements">Presentations and Supplements</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12136217">PWS/SOW & WAWF Training</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/SPAWAR+e-Commerce+Central+Training">SPAWAR e-Commerce Central Training</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Large+Contracts">Large Contracts</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Acquisition+Planning">Acquisition Planning</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Pre-Award">Pre-Award</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Post-Award">Post-Award</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Simplified+Acquisition">Simplified Acquisition</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Checklists">Checklist</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Required+Forms+and+Memos">Required Forms and Memos</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Guidance">Guidance</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Purchase+Card">Purchase Card</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/About">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Instructions">Instructions</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Desk+Guides">Desk Guides</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Forms">Forms</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/PCIBs">PCIBs</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Purchase+Card+Training">Purchase Card Training</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Assignment+of+APCs+to+AOs">Assignment of APCs to AOs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Customers">Customers</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/General+Information">General Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Large+Contracts+Guidance">Large Contracts Guidance</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Acquisition+Planning">Acquisition Planning</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Pre-Award">Pre-Award</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Post-Award">Post-Award</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Simplified+Acquisition+Guidance">Simplified Acquisition Guidance</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Checklists">Checklists</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Required+Forms+and+Memos">Required Forms and Memos</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/.Guidance">Guidance</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/CDRL">CDRL</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Checklist+Repository">Checklist Repository</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135219">Contracts Information Bulletins (CIBs)</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Center+Wide+Contracts">Center Wide Contracts</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135872">Government Furnished Property (GFP)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/CORs">CORs</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Navy+ERP+Material+Management">Navy ERP Material Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12136000">IT Support (ITAG)</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Introduction+to+IT+Support">Introduction to IT Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/New+Employee+Resources">New Employee Resources</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Microsoft+Office">Microsoft Office</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Hardware+Support">Hardware Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Network+Drives">Network Drives</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Adobe+Acrobat">Adobe Acrobat</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12150271">SPS/PD²</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Desk+Guide">Desk Guide</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Integrity+Tool">Integrity Tool</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Navy+ERP">Navy ERP</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135229">Laptops & Remote Connectivity</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Important+Websites">Important Websites</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12135224">Misc.</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Confluence/JIRA Issue Log</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Document+Management">Document Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Image+Management">Image Management</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Reserve+a+Resource">Reserve a Resource</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/0607+Training+Room">0607 Training Room</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Conference+Rooms">Conference Rooms</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Vehicles">Vehicles</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://hub.sd.spawar.navy.mil/display/CON/Contact+Us">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div><h1>This is a sample to see if the navigation overlay is going to cause a problem</h1></div>
```

Comment: Hi, please include a [mcve] in your post.

Comment: Hi. I am not sure what else I can put as far as examples. Simply, the navigation bar is not overlaying properly in confluence when I add an HTML header. There are a couple of pictures.

Comment: Did you visit the link I shared? In order to debug problems with code, we need to see the code. Specifically, an MCVE. We cannot debug a screenshot.

Comment: Oh. Alright will include the html and css. Thanks

Comment: @Lisbon have you tried adding a z-index to the menu (`#primary_nav_wrap ul`)? For example, `z-index:99;`

Comment: Hi @PeterDempsey Not yet as I am new to web pages. I was a SQL guy so this is all new to me. Will try that.

Comment: Hi @PeterDempsey that works! Thanks! I need to start taking web pages classes haha. I used to be a SQL Developer but moved to a different position so this is all new to me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Lisbon no problem - take a look at https://codyhouse.co/courses-library/, they have some very useful courses and guides.